# SELECT multiple single (LIMIT 1) records based on a variable condition

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, database-design

I have two tables, `charts` and `chart_entries` and I want to get the current top 5 chart positions (based on selecting the latest `chart_entries` at a given position).

Is there a way of making this a single query? Ideally my charts will have anything up to 500 positions so it's not really feasible to have multiple queries like this.

In rails I'm currently using this method in `Chart.rb`

```
def table
  (1..5).each do |i|
    chart_entries.where(position: i).order('entered_at DESC').first
  end
end
```

to generate the following SQL

```
SELECT "chart_entries".* FROM "chart_entries" WHERE "chart_entries"."chart_id" = 1 AND "chart_entries"."position" = 1 ORDER BY entered_at DESC LIMIT 1
SELECT "chart_entries".* FROM "chart_entries" WHERE "chart_entries"."chart_id" = 1 AND "chart_entries"."position" = 2 ORDER BY entered_at DESC LIMIT 1
SELECT "chart_entries".* FROM "chart_entries" WHERE "chart_entries"."chart_id" = 1 AND "chart_entries"."position" = 3 ORDER BY entered_at DESC LIMIT 1
SELECT "chart_entries".* FROM "chart_entries" WHERE "chart_entries"."chart_id" = 1 AND "chart_entries"."position" = 4 ORDER BY entered_at DESC LIMIT 1
SELECT "chart_entries".* FROM "chart_entries" WHERE "chart_entries"."chart_id" = 1 AND "chart_entries"."position" = 5 ORDER BY entered_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

This is the table structure (postgresql)

```
CREATE TABLE chart_entries (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  chart_id integer,
  entity_id integer,
  "position" integer,
  entered_at timestamp without time zone,
  locale character varying(255)
);

CREATE TABLE charts (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255)
);
```

This was my final solution

```
chart_entries.where(position: [1..5]).group('position, id').having('entered_at = MAX(entered_at)').order('position ASC')
```

Comment: can you post your table's structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a good candidate for `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    chart_entries
WHERE
    chart_id = 1
    AND position BETWEEN 1 AND 5
GROUP BY
    position
HAVING
    entered_at = MAX(entered_at)
```

Using `GROUP BY` will select a single row for each position. The `HAVING` clause should select the latest one by date (you could also use the primary key for this as it *should* be the latest one - unless you insert custom dates).

Instead of needing to write each individual `position` available, you can use `BETWEEN` in your `WHERE` clause to get "all positions *between* 1 and 5" (or whatever your range is).

Comment: Nothing MySQL specific about that, it's bog standard basic SQL.

Comment: @CraigRinger Removed reference to `MySQL` to avoid any confusion. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAX` & `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT MAX("chart_entries".id) FROM "chart_entries" 
WHERE "chart_entries"."chart_id" = 1 AND "chart_entries"."position" IN (1,2,3,4,5) 
ORDER BY entered_at DESC 
GROUP BY  "chart_entries"."position"
```